# Read lines from a file and compare their equality

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a progam to read a text file and compare its lines. I want to store them in an array, but I do not how to do this and how to compare, if they are equal.

```
package pantoum;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pantoum {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //get filename input from user
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the full file name: ");
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
        File inputFile = new File(fileName);

        if (inputFile.exists()){

            //create scanner to read file
            Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);

            //while (input.hasNext());{ 
            String title = input.next();
            System.out.println(title);

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, that file does not exist.");
        }

    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you use a `Set`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare?

Comment: Also, do you need to know what is duplicated or just if there are duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i personally prefer to use buffered reader when it comes to reading from a text file.

```
boolean equal=false;
String lines[] =new [10];

// or however long the array needs to be.

int count=0;
BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<Name of file>"));
                do {

                    lines[count] = infile.readLine();
                   count++;
                } while (lines[count] != null);

for(int i=0;i<lines.length();i++) {

for(int j = i+1; j<lines.length()-1;j++){



if(lines[i].equals(lines[j])){
    equal=true; 
    system.out.print(lines[i]+" and "+lines[j]+" are equal");

}}}

if(!equal){
system.out.print("Sorry your text did not equal any text from the text file");
}
```

i hope this helped and i hope i have explained everything well enough for you to understand, if not feel free to ask.

Comment: If `java-8` is allowed, you can build the array as `String[] lines = infile.lines().toArray(String[]::new);`. As a bonus, you don't have to guess at the size of the array ahead of time.

Comment: It might be better to stream the lines into a map that counts their frequency to help with finding duplicates. `Map<String, Long> freq = infile.lines().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s ->s, Collectors.counting()));`

Comment: yeah, that option does sound better. Was not aware of the '.toArray(String[]::new);' method in java.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would read each line into a String[] position and then in a loop check if `String[i].equals(String[j])`. If you need a rough idea how to code this let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use scanner's nextLine() method to get an entire line and then compare them using String.equals()

something like

```
String line1 = input.nextLine();
String line2 = input.nextLine();
if(line1.equals(line2){
   doStuff();
}
```

Comment: What if there are more than two lines?

Comment: @bradimus I was just providing an example of how to use input.nextLine(), not trying to write the entire solution.